# how to send huge text via header of UrlConnection in Android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to send an image to my Web API server. My idea is convert to base64 the byte array of the image, then add the string to header of urlconnection. I tested with short string, it worked normally. But when I tried to send a long string, it return "FileNotFoundException". This is my code for URL connection

```
URL url;
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

try {
        url = new URL(link);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept","*/*");

        if (mAvatar != null) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            mAvatar.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
            String enImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);

            //urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(enImage.length()));
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Image", enImage);
        }

        InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);
        int data = isw.read();
        while (data != -1) {
            char current = (char) data;
            data = isw.read();
            result += current;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(Constants.TAG, ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

What do I miss? Anyway, this is only my idea for that problem. Any other ideas are appreciate!

Comment: Why not just send it as the body ?

Comment: you are using `POST method, so why do you want to send your huge data in the headers?

Comment: Simply just upload image into any folder, and save path in `SQL` table, using `Web-Api`

Comment: @M.WaqasPervez do u mean something like http://url?value=my_string

Comment: @pskink I just pick 1 available method. There is no problem with the method, I can use config any method in my server.

Comment: let smash your image on a smaller packages and build a big one on your server

Comment: @AbdulKawee I don't know how to upload an image from android and take it in web API controller :(

Comment: @grabarz121 hmm, I thought about that before. I just want to know that I can send huge text to my server or not. That will be my last solution if there is no other one.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an `HTTPPOST` request with the following code in which you can send you `base64` image as string as a body parameter.

```
    try {

        URL serverUrl = new URL(url);


        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) serverUrl.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept","*/*");

 JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
   if (mAvatar != null) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        mAvatar.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        String enImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);


        object.put("Image",enImage);

    }

        OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

        writer.write(object.toString());
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
 StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        if (connection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
           String line = null;

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);

    }
    return result.toString();

 }
```

Comment: How can I read data from this OutputStream on server side? The request type is [HttpRequestMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage(v=vs.118).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

What i have done is to send image to `Web-Api`

**1st**

Add Dependency

`compile 'net.gotev:uploadservice:2.1'`

**2nd**

In your activity

```
private class ProcessUpload extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //getting the actual path of the image
        String path = getPath(filePath);

        //Uploading code
        try {
            String uploadId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();


            new MultipartUploadRequest(context, uploadId, getString(R.string.localAdd)+"/Example/uploadimage.php")
                    .addFileToUpload(path, "image") //Adding file
                    .addParameter("username", userName)
                    .addParameter("title", title1)
                    .addParameter("description",description1)
                    .addParameter("price",price1)
                    .addParameter("number",number1)
                    .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                    .setMaxRetries(2)
                    .startUpload(); //Starting the upload

        } catch (Exception exc) {
            Toast.makeText(context, exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pDialog.setTitle("Connection to Server");
        pDialog.setMessage("Uploading Image ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String json) {

        pDialog.dismiss();

        Intent intent = new Intent(NewAddActivity.this, AddsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
       // finish();

    }
}
```

And simply get in your Api and save

Comment: hmm, my server is Web API of dotNet. So, how can I access the image there? In url or somewhere in Request? The type of Request is [HttpRequestMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: @NgoKimHuynh Sorry for late reply was busy, I have a `php` api , can share with you, it will give you a complete idea what is happening in the backend, and you can easily integrate that code in `dotNet`

Answer (score 0):

Thank to everyone, finally, I made the solution for my issue.

On Android, use OutputStream and BufferedWriter to write string to stream. Then on my sever (It is WebAPI of .net), use StreamReader to take the string.

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream);
reader.BaseStream.Position = 0;

string value = reader.ReadToEnd();
```